# Определение языка текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, естественный-язык

Есть текст. Нужно определить язык этого текста: русский или украинский. Использовал api от яндекс переводчика, но там стоит лимит на один миллион символов в день. 1М это мало. Может кто то знает какие то библиотеки на python3?

**upd**: мне хотя бы узнать, является ли текст украинским.

Comment: Возможно вот эта библиотека подойдет: https://github.com/CLD2Owners/cld2 , и пример как заставить работать с Python:  
https://github.com/mikemccand/chromium-compact-language-detector

Answer (score 6):

Можно воспользоваться [langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect):

```
In [65]: from langdetect import detect

In [66]: %paste
detect('"Зоряні війни" офіційно оголосили назву нового епізоду')

## -- End pasted text --
Out[66]: 'uk'

In [67]: %paste
detect('Дональд Трамп подписал указ об официальном выходе США из Транстихоокеанского партнерства')

## -- End pasted text --
Out[67]: 'ru'
```

Если нужно сделать оценку:

```
In [78]: from langdetect import detect_langs

In [79]: %paste
detect_langs('Спробуй вгадати який це "язык"')

## -- End pasted text --
Out[79]: [ru:0.7142865675080949, uk:0.28571330147081586]

In [80]: %paste
detect_langs('Ты говоришь на "мові"')

## -- End pasted text --
Out[80]: [uk:0.9999979837984605]
```

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой и быстрый вариант использовать [cld2-cffi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cld2-cffi):

```
pip3 install cld2-cffi
```

Пример кода:

```
import cld2

# текст на Русском 
details = cld2.detect("Это мой образец текста")
print(str(details))

# Вывод:
# Detections(is_reliable=True, bytes_found=43, details=(Detection(language_name='RUSSIAN', language_code='ru', percent=97, score=658.0), Detection(language_name='Unknown', language_code='un', percent=0, score=0.0), Detection(language_name='Unknown', language_code='un', percent=0, score=0.0)))

# текст на Украинском  
details = cld2.detect("Це мій зразок тексту")

# Вывод:
# Detections(is_reliable=True, bytes_found=39, details=(Detection(language_name='UKRAINIAN', language_code='uk', percent=97, score=862.0), Detection(language_name='Unknown', language_code='un', percent=0, score=0.0), Detection(language_name='Unknown', language_code='un', percent=0, score=0.0)))
```