# Как узнать какой язык используется в тексте

Tags: python, строки

Есть массив строчек

```
[
   'Something in English и что-то на русском',
   'किसी भाषा में कुछ Something in English',
   'Something in English'
]
```

Как можно проверить эти строчки и получить только ту, в которой есть только английский язык?

Возможно ли решить данную задачу с помощью регулярных выражений?

Comment: укажите в вопросе (в метках) язык программирования

Comment: В общем случае - скорее всего никак. Если постараться, можно придумать такие фразы, которые будут выглядеть идентично или почти идентично сразу в нескольких языках

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Определение языка текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618528/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На python вот так можно:

```py
from langdetect import detect

lang = detect("Ein, zwei, drei, vier")

print lang
#output: de
```

или можно так:

```py
from textblob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob("bonjour")
b.detect_language()
```

Comment: О, хорошо что напомнили. Главное я помнил раньше про эти библиотеки, но недавно был вопрос тоже что-то про языки, а я про них и не вспомнил, пришлось велосипеды городить.

Comment: зачем вы пишите на втором питоне?

Answer (score 0):

На php можно так.

```
$array = [
   'Something in English и что-то на русском',
   'किसी भाषा में कुछ Something in English',
   'Something in English'
];

foreach($array as $str) {
    if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', $str))
    {
       echo $str; // строка содержит только английские буквы и цифры
    }
}
```

Comment: Латинские только, а не английские :) В итальянском тоже такие например, только меньше. Плюс, у вас регулярка не соответствует комментарию совсем )) У вас `^` — отрицание)

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, с отрицанием всё хорошо.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему? В строке, допустим, нету `A-Za-z0-9 `, `preg_match` вернёт `false`, отрицание в условии `!` приведёт в `true` и выведется то, что под комментом «строка содержит только английские буквы и цифры»?..

Comment: А не, всё правильно: если есть хотя бы один символ НЕ не являющийся латинской буквой, или цифрой или пробелом, то «строка содержит только английские буквы и цифры» ...

Comment: По моей логике я бы написал такое выражение через регулярку: `/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/`.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, да, немного мутновато записано, но работать почти будет. Почти, потому что знаки препинания тоже запрещены))) Но можно подопиливать.